# AngularJS + Single Core CPU = Almost 100% CPU

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I've built a large `AngularJS` application that performed fine on until now.
My problem started when some users(with very old computers that have **one** CPU) complained about the application being extremely slow.

I've opened the task manager and I can see that the tab is on 70% - 100% CPU always(When using a single core CPU).

Now since this works great on stronger computers, I'm not sure I have a performance issue and if I do, I don't really know how to check this(I can't check this with performance tools on chrome).

Is there any way to handle this? To tell `Angular` to perform it's digest cycles **less** times?
Has anyone encountered a similar issue? **Any** tip will be great for me.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1534

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is with the single CPU rather than IE8. I'll edit my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 6):

I have never seen ways to reduce the number of times cycles are called.

However there are several ways to improve the performance of your application.

First, to have an idea of the performance from your computer you may install [Batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang) which provide a tab for performance analysis.

Once you have this you may focus on the following:

1. Disable the watchers that won't be use anymore
2. Avoid ng-repeat if possible and/or use the [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) directive
3. Use pagination to have smaller sets of data

For more details you may refer to the following articles:

- https://www.exratione.com/2013/12/considering-speed-and-slowness-in-angularjs/
- https://coderwall.com/p/d_aisq
- http://www.slideshare.net/JohnMeiss/10-astuces-pour-ameliorer-les-performances-de-son-application-angularjs-ngparis-meetup-11-meetic (Part of it is in French)

Comment: +1 - Thanks for your answer. I don't really want to waist my time on fixing performance issues since on computers with standard CPU's I have no problems.
My application already does the things you suggested but it looks like angular's digests use a lot on CPU(e.g. when I move the mouse cursor a lot it's easy to see).

Comment: Do you have examples of issues with those single core computer? Like the  issue with moving your mouse a lot?